# Run a script once an element changes

Tags: jquery

How would I monitor an element, for example a picklist or updated form object, for any changes and then code once any change occurs?

Comment: You are looking for the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#element-id').live('eventType', function(e) {
   //do stuff here
});
```

The 'eventType' will be different based on the type of object '#element-id' is.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").change(function(){
    //do your stuff
});
```

will probably do it

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery's `change` method.

```
$('#element').change(function(){
    // ... 
});
```